# ruby on rails gem error - No such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to use the koala gem per these instructions: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki

I did a gem install koala. I see the gem in the list of installed gems.

The instructions say to add 
require 'rubygems'
require 'koala'

It doesn't say where. I tried it to add the lines to the beginning of one of my controllers.
Then I also tried it in the initializer file:
C:\Documents and Settings\mtariq\blog\config\initializers\koala.rb

I always get the same error: 
no such file to load -- koala

I installed the gem.. so what 'file' is it trying to load?

Any help would be appreciated. I know I must be doing something stupid but can't find any clues.

Mariam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running rails 3, just add the koala gem to your Gemfile, then run 'bundle install'. No need to require any library.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'koala'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. When is the 'require' statement used then? Or is that an alternative way or older way to include a library?

Comment: I believe the instructions refer to ruby code in general (e.g. standalone ruby program). Within the rails framework however, you don't need to do this since this is already being taken care of by Bundler. In other words, if you were to use this gem (or any other gem as a matter of fact) in a standalone ruby program, then you would need to require the appropriate libraries.